# Creating RPC through intergromat apps returns 404

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am trying to create an RPC that lists departments in a service. However, the endpoint for listing all departments returns an HTTP `404` error if no departments exist. It seems that the 'valid' directive does not work when the status code is greater than `399`. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to mark a response status greater than 399 as OK. The [valid](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/structure-blocks/api/handling-responses#valid) directive serves for the other direction - marking a 200 status as an error. The only thing I can recommend is putting the following error handling code inside your RPC:

```
"error": {
  "404": {
    "type": "DataError",
    "message": "No departments found. --ServiceName-- marks this case as an error - please switch to the Map mode to save."
  }
}
```

That will at least help the user know what's going on when they try to set up the module input.

Here's what this would look like inside a [Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUzen.png).